# Running ubuntu 10.04 on Inspiron 1720, screen resolution woes

Tags: ubuntu, resolution, display, ubuntu-10.04, dell-inspiron

Ok my screen resolution is stuck at 800x600.  I'm trying ubuntu on my Inspiron 1720 laptop.

How can I get a higher resolution?

I tried ubuntu on my desktop many moons ago, and now giving it another shot.

I hope this is an easy fix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's been significant changes in the Ubuntu graphics (X11) code and you're using an Ubuntu more than 2 years old. Download an Ubuntu 12.04 desktop live CD and see if you can reconfigure the display resolution appropriately.

Don't try to configure X11 unless you have to and have day or two of free time - it's complex and idiosyncratic and while there's voluminous documentation available it's not well written and is also mostly out of date. eg. The standard config file (/etc/X11/Xorg.conf) disappeared in recent releases (though still supported for backwards compatibility) and was replaced with the not yet well documented HAL (Hardware Abstraction Layer) configured in /etc/hal/fdi and /usr/share/hal/fdi.

Comment: Good info.  Do notice, however, that the question was asked 2 years ago :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=83973

It lists a step by step guide as well as how to troubleshoot problems (down at the bottom.)

Comment: the bottom of the 1st page?  Mine doesnt' even have that config file.

Comment: You don't have an xorg configuration? Try searching your system for it. Without a configuration, you wouldn't be seeing anything.

Comment: when I type sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg it asks for my pwd, then does nothing?

Comment: Did you double check to make sure that you video card driver was automatically discovered and installed?

Comment: James, not sure how to do that?  If the resolution is so poor, doesn't that mean it wasn't discovered? :)

Comment: I would assume so or the monitor wasn't discovered (resulting in the lowest possible resolution.) Let me ask you this, when you installed Ubuntu from the Live CD, was the resolution and screen normal? Or was it stuck in 800x600 as well?